# How to divde the values on fixed input for different inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textbox:-

```
<label>Total Amount</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="totalAmount" disabled="disabled" ng-value="a.one+a.two+a.three+a.four" style="width:150px;height:30px"/>
The ng-value above is a sum of other four textboxes values.
```

There are other six textboxes:-

```
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.mul1" ng-value="dividedValue(totalAmount,b.val1)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.val1" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.mul1)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
       <input type="text" ng-model="b.mul2" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.val2)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.val2" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.mul2)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.mul3" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.val3)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.val3" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.mul3)"/>
```

What I am trying to do here is keeping `totalAmount` to be fixed and according to that `mul` and `val` changes. Example:- `totalAmount = mul1*val1, mul1 = totalAmount/val1, val1 = totalAmount/mul1`.
If user changes mul1 then val1 changes(totalAmount/val1) and vice versa.

In my directive code:-

```
scope.dividedValue = function(a,b){
         return a / b;
 }
```

But this method returns nothing.Can anyone tell me the mistake.

Comment: `val1` , `val2` is from?

Comment: I am able to change the val1 when I input some value in mul1 but viceversa is not working also when I replace both val1 and mul1 values then after entering value again in the input the function is calling but division is not happening.

Comment: because your function will not be triggered. as you are not using two way data binding. what is your expectation tell me.

Comment: I want totalAmount to be fixed. When user enter some value in mul1 then val1 should change to totalAmount/mul1, and when user change val1 then mul1 should become totalAmount/val1. The values should keep changing.

Comment: sorry, I am not,

Comment: you can achieve that using `ng-change="dividedValue(totalAmount,b.val1)` and update the corresponding `b.val1` so that its changed in the textbox because of two way binding. is this clear or need more explanation

Comment: If I change ng-value to ng-change then how to ng-model will update.I nee to assign the divided value to the ng-model that is why I am using the ng-value.

Comment: you should be having a unique identifier, using if conditions in the code corresponding `ng-model` can be updated, `ng-model` value is different from that of the one you are calling in the method `ng-value` as `val1 - mul1`

Comment: so you got it ?

Comment: I already change the ng-model to b.val1 and b.mul1 but now on ng-change the function is not even calling. I got what are u trying to say but the logic is not working for me

Comment: I m not getting your point. **function is not even calling** what you mean! when is it not called

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in functions name it must be "dividedValue but its divisedValue"

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the right value, `ng-model` is `b.val1`, `b.mul1` and so on but you are passing just `val1`, `mul1` in the method call.

```
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.mul1" ng-value="dividedValue(totalAmount,b.val1)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.val1" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.mul1)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
       <input type="text" ng-model="b.mul2" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.val2)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.val2" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.mul2)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.mul3" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.val3)"/>
<label>Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="b.val3" ng-value= "dividedValue(totalAmount,b.mul3)"/>
```

As said in above  answer change the method name as there was a typo

```
dividedValue(a,b){
    return a/b;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>



<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="OnlineShopping">
<label>Total Amount</label>
    <input type="text" ng-module="a" ng-value="a=dividedValue(6,2)" disabled="disabled" style="width:150px;height:30px"/>
 {{a}}
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("OnlineShopping", function($scope)
 { 
    $scope.dividedValue = function(a,b){
         return a / b;
 }   
   
 })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```